# How to store jsonarray to string array android

Tags: android

How to store jsonarray to arraylist string? please any help is much appreciated.
this is my jsonarray

```
{  
   "ids":[  
      {  
         "noid":"2"
      },
      {  
         "noid":"3"
      }
   ],
   "success":1
}
```

I want to store the values of identity "noid" in arraylist.
here is my code in android.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("qid", qsid));

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            main_url, "GET", params);

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt("success");
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray idSet = json
                                .getJSONArray("ids"); // JSON Array
                            for(int i = 0; i < idSet.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject outputId = idSet.getJSONObject(i);

                                arrayList.add(outputId.getString("noid").toString());
                            }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), json.getString("result"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        return null;
    }
```

and here is my php file.

```
<?php
require_once 'mobile_question_query.php';

$j = array();

if(isset($_GET["qid"])){


$id = $_GET['qid'];


$fetchallqObject = new Questions();

if(!empty($id)){
        $json_array = $fetchallqObject->fetchAllQuestionsID($id);

        echo json_encode($json_array);
}else{

    $j['result'] = "No id!";
    echo json_encode($j);
}
}else{
    echo "no id found";
}

?>
```

if i check the array if arraylist is empty, it return always true.

Comment: use gson parsing

Comment: Your code looks fine, what issue you have ??

Comment: my issue is the arraylist which i want to store my jsonarray is always empty

Answer (score 1):

Use Gson library.

```
List<String> list= new Gson().fromJson(idSet, new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>(){}.getType());
```

Comment: is Gson has the library?? want to try this